# swift3 how to save Photo info in SQLite from photo library?

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift3, photo

swift3

hello, i want to save photo in sqlite and load it anytime.

first, choice photo from photo library.
second, save it in sqlite ( how? )
last, i want to show the photo from sqlite information

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType] as! NSString
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    if mediaType.isEqual(to: kUTTypeImage as String) {
        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
        let strBase64:String = (imageData?.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters))!
        imageInfo = strBase64 // <imageInfo will saved in sqlite

        imageView.image = image
    }
}
```

this code is how to im bring photo.

Comment: you can Use Base 64. it turns the image into a string . . or you can save the path of file in sqlite and access that any time you want.

Comment: @roozbehmo thank you. i solved it with your advice !

Comment: happy to help ;) if it helped you can u like the comment? :)

Comment: you need to save only path of image in sqlite and then retrieve image through this image path .

Comment: @KKRocks updated my source. is that save path of image? or image?

Comment: path of image...

Comment: @HoonyB : best way to store image nsdata

Comment: if store image nsdata to sqlite then database size will be increase .

Answer (score 0):

You should save only the path of photo in sqlite and use that path to show photo in future.
So your steps should be:

1) Get photo from photo library

2) Save photo in document directory

3) store the path of photo in sqlite